# How to you display a webview url in a UISearchBar

Tags: swift, uiwebview, uisearchbar

I have made a search-browser app and I can't figure out how to display the webview's URL for the current website you are on.

I tried `mySearchBar.text = myWebView.url` and it doesn't work.

I found out how you can do it with print but that doesn't help me.

```
print("URL: \(String(describing: myWebView.url))")
```

Comment: `mySearchBar.text = myWebView.url` won't work because you can't directly assign a `URL` value to a `String` property. Did you try `mySearchBar.text = myWebView.url.absoluteString` ?

Comment: Also, when posting a question, never say "it doesn't work". Explain clearly in what way it isn't working. Do you get compiler errors/warnings? Does it crash? Does it behave differently than expected? Include specific details about the issue to make it easier for people to help.